# Помогите правильно объявить аннотацию @Autowired

Tags: java, sql, spring, dba

Есть код:

```
@RestController
public class RestApiController {
    DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler();
    @Autowired
    private SessionDBA sessionDBA;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/1",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            headers = "Accept=application/json",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> addSess(String session) throws SQLException {
        dbHandler.addUserSession(session);
            return ResponseEntity.status(200).body("");
    }
}
```

Приложение падает с ошибкой:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field sessionDBA in server.RestApiController required a bean of type 'db_connector.DBA.SessionDBA' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'db_connector.DBA.SessionDBA' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59520', transport: 'socket'

Comment: покажите этот класс SessionDBA

Comment: @Дмитрий
public interface SessionDBA extends CrudRepository<Session, String> {
}
Он пустой, тк нужная функция есть в CrudRepository

Comment: значит вопрос в структуре ваших пакетов. ваш бин SessionDBA  спринг найти не может. и тут 2 варианта: его нет в принципе, он находится в недосягаемости

Comment: interface SessionDBA помечен аннотацией @Repository?
В конфигурации есть аннотация @EnableJpaRepositories?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была не во всех сущностях, а только в тех, что не помечены аннотацией @Entity.
Из-за этого была ошибка.